# How to handle onerror on html5 picture

Tags: html, image, onerror

I found this question : [jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)
its works great for img tag,
but when I try to use it for picture tag, its doesn't work.

first I try to catch th source failed:

```
    $('picture source').on('error', function () {
        loadBackupImage($('picture source').first());
    });
```

and the error didn't fired.

then I try to get the error on the alternate img tag.
but I can't get the specific source - srcset attribute.

also, when I change the img.src. it's still return error on the browser. even so I see that's the img.src is correct.

thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I found the way:
the tag picture fired onerror as img, and the img has siblings - source.

```
$("img").on('error', function () {
    $(this).siblings("source").attr("srcset","mybackup.jpg")
});
```

one more complicatted: I stored the differnce image for each source in attribute data-image, and displays the correct backup image

```
$("img").on('error', function () {
    var image = $(this).siblings("source").attr("data-image");
    $(this).siblings("source").attr("srcset",image);
});
```

hope you will find its helpfull.